# How to pass variable from ajax function to another ajax function?

Tags: jquery

I want to know how to pass value from ajax function to another ajax I've tried this code but It does not work. Anyone know how to do it the right way? Thanks!

```
    $("#button").click(function(){
    var passedValue = '';
    $.ajax({
        url://
        type://
        success:function(data){
            if(typeof==="object"){
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                passedValue = data[i]["passedThis"];
            }
        }
    }
    });
    $.ajax({
        data: { receivedPassed: passedValue;}
    });
});
```

Comment: My thoughts are that ajax calls are by default ran `asynchronously` meaning that they will all fire at the same time of invocation without waiting on the next. Because of this, `passedValue` will be null. if you add `async:false;` to the first ajax call, it shuold work.

Comment: But, it will give the appearance that your webpage has locked up.

Comment: 2 issues. Your variable is declared inside the click function, so it'll be out of scope when you need it later. Also, the ajax calls are asynchronous, so the second ajax call will try to read the variable before it's ready.

Comment: @LeeTaylor: Just a minor note: it won't be out of scope! JavaScript has function scope, and the variable will remain valid in the nested functions.

Comment: @qwzjk Ah, yes. I couldn't tell because of the tabbing/braces.

Comment: @LeeTaylor: Ah, sorry, I can see how that's an easy mistake to make 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those requests are asynchronous, so `passedValue` isn't ready by the time the second one is sent. You'll probably want to send them in order:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: //
        type: //
        success: function(data) {
            var passedValue;

            if(typeof (?) === "object") {
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    passedValue = data[i]["passedThis"];
                }

                $.ajax({
                    data: { receivedPassed: passedValue }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Also, you're overwriting `passedValue` each time through that loop. Did you mean `+=` instead of `=`, or to use an array, or something?

Comment: @BrainedWashed: Well, you had `typeof === "object"` in your original code. I take it you took out the actual variable? I added the `(?)` to make it more obvious that it's a placeholder.

Comment: I have question what if I will make that $.ajax like function receivedValue()? can I still get the passedValue?

Comment: @BrainedWashed: Yup - as long as `passedValue` is declared inside that scope and the other callback is somewhere within the same scope too.

Comment: this is what I mean i'm really having hard time please help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449655/how-can-i-pass-this-specific-variable-im-using-jquery-ajax) :)

Answer (score 1):

Chain the AJAX calls using [`.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/), and filter data from the first call to the second using [`.pipe()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/):

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: //
      type: //
    }).pipe(function (data) {
      var passedValue = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        passedValue[i] = data[i]["passedThis"];
      }
      return passedValue;
    }).then(function (receivedPassed) {
      $.ajax({
        data: { receivedPassed: passedValue }
      }
    }
});
```

Also note that the `.success()` callback will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8:

> Deprecation Notice: The `jqXHR.success()`, `jqXHR.error()`, and
>   `jqXHR.complete()` callbacks will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8.

Comment: It would probably be a good idea for them to move that deprecation notice higher up the page 