# How can I pass this specific variable I'm using jquery-ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I want to pass the "passedThisValue" to my "start_battle" function and use the "start_battle" function in my "Rematch". But the modal just hangs why is this happening? what could be wrong? Please help! :) Thank you.

CODE:

```
function start_battle(){
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            receivePassedValue: passedThisValue
        },
        success: function(data){

        }
    });
}
$("#start_battle").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        success: function(data){
            var toAppend = '';
            if(typeof data === "object"){
                var passedThisValue = '';
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    passedThisValue = data[i]['thisValue']; 
                }

                start_battle(); // can I still get the passedThisValue?

            }
        }
    });
    $("#battle").dialog({
        modal:true,
        buttons: {
            "Rematch": function(){
                start_battle(); // can I still get the passedThisValue?
            }
        }
    });
    $("#battle").show(500);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call a function, you don't use `function start_battle();`, you just use `start_battle();`.

When you pass a value to a function, you need to use this syntax: `start_battle(param1, param2);`.

When you want to get a value from a function, you need to return it in the function, like so:

```
function start_battle(param1) {
    // Do something
    return param1;
}
```

When you want to store a returned value from a function, you do something like: `var returned = start_battle(param1);`

And the fact that you don't know why the modal just hangs, means that you didn't check the browser's error console, which can hold some pretty important information on what's wrong. Try checking that and posting here so we can see the current problem

Comment: sorry I just mis type calling the function ^^, start_battle(passedThisValue) ? I use the firebug and it ddnt proceed to start_battle()

Answer (score 1):

Your function declaration seems a little off. I think you should leave off the `$` from `function`. Just do this

```
function start_battle() {
```

Also, when you're calling a function, you don't say `function` before it. And if you want to pass a value to the function, you have to put it inside the parenthesis, both when defining the function and when calling it. Like this

```
function start_battle(someValue) {
    // do some stuff with someValue
}

// inside your .click, call start_battle like this
start_battle(passedThisValue);
```

Pretty basic stuff. But either one of those problems could be causing the hang, which was likely a javascript error.

Comment: sorry I just mis type calling the function ^^, start_battle(passedThisValue) ? I use the firebug and it ddnt proceed to start_battle()